# Creating bordered view with custom shape

Tags: ios, uiview, layer, uibezierpath

I want to create a view as shown in screenshot below-

[image]

Now I do not know how to create a bordered `UIView` with 4 rounded corners and having two more rounded portions above the header view as shown in screen shot below.

[image]

**Note**:

*1) I know how to create `UIView` with 1-4 rounded corners.*

*2) I need to create the above view without using any Image.*

Any hint/ help related to the creation of above view with more than four rounded corners is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: it would be better to use  background image and Place views on it.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan, thanks for your reply, actually I do not want to use any Image to create above view, I need to create above view using uiview only

Answer (score 0):

First, design an image as you want with same size as of you view. Than 
set that image a background image for you view.

custom_view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];

Comment: thanks for you quick answer, but I do not want to use Image, I need to create above view using uiview only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the cornerRadius property on your views like so

myView.layer.cornerRadius = someFloatValue

Or use this : (you may need to adapt it to your need)

//// Rectangle Drawing
UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(30, 30, 196, 74) cornerRadius: 10];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[rectanglePath fill];

//// Rectangle 2 Drawing
UIBezierPath* rectangle2Path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(80, 22, 96, 14) cornerRadius: 7];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[rectangle2Path fill];

SWIFT version :

//// Rectangle Drawing
let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(30, 30, 196, 74), cornerRadius: 10)
UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
rectanglePath.fill()

//// Rectangle 2 Drawing
let rectangle2Path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(80, 22, 96, 14), cornerRadius: 7)
UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
rectangle2Path.fill()

Comment: thanks for your answer, but setting corner radius on view's layer will only make it's 4 corner's radial and I want more than that, basically a custom shape with 6 radial corners.